# Restrict external CSS impact on local react components or HTML elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, reactjs

I'm using few external CSS in the HTML page of my React application. After rendering the components the external CSS is affecting my React components UI and distorting them. But, I need the external CSS to render Header (a specific part of the HTML page) but not affect the rest of the page elements.

Would it be possible to restrict this behavior to only specific of few elements in the page?

I'm using react-scripts for quick application development. Based on the approach proposed I can take control of the build and deployment process on need.

Example:

page.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Test HTML</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="page.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="outer">
       <h1>This is an outer H1/h1>
        <p>This is an outer P</p>
    </div>
    <div id="inner">
        <h1>This is an inner H1</h1>
        <p>This is an outer P</p>
    </div>
    <div id="root"></div> <!-- This is where my React components would be 
                          rendered -->
</body>
```

page.css

```
@charset-"utf-8";
h1 {color:red}
p {color:green}
body {font-weight:bold;}
```

I want the external css file page.css to not to effect h1 and p tags in div id="inner" section and as well as elements that would be rendered into div id="root".

Comment: How does it affect other components? probably your CSS is wrong, or the `className` used is overriding the UI library you are using

Comment: just pull out the styles you need for the Header and add them to your own CSS so you can strip out the externall CSS

Comment: Use dev tools to find the exact class name of the header component and then overwrite any css properties you need to.

Answer (score 1):

You can create another CSS for your React Application and import it to your React. in that CSS file just select your react App Id which elements will render in there (in most case the Id is root) then select the child tag in root or anyhow you want to select then give a style to it in this case for example it will be like :

```
app.css in there you can select like  
#root h1 {color:white} and .... 
and import it like import "./app.css" ("./YourCssAddress.css") to your react app
```